# Timing of vectorised string operations in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I'm getting 5x worse performance with the DataFrame `str.replace` wrapper than the inbuilt function. Does anyone know what's causing this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'word':['bird']*100000})
%timeit df.word.str.replace('bird','theword')
%timeit df.word.map(lambda x: x.replace('bird','theword'))
1 loops, best of 3: 266 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 55.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: Most likely because `Series.str.replace` is using regex and `str.replace` is not. The higher functionality of regex has a higher price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `str.replace` will be able to handle NaNs, while the custom replace with lambda will error on that:

```
In [17]: df.iloc[0,0] = np.nan

In [18]: df.word.str.replace('bird','theword').head()
Out[18]:
0        NaN
1    theword
2    theword
3    theword
4    theword
Name: word, dtype: object

In [19]: df.word.map(lambda x: x.replace('bird','theword'))

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

[Internally](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/v0.16.2/pandas/core/strings.py#L295), `str.replace` also uses `lambda x: x.replace(pat, repl, n)` (if you are not using the *case* or *flags* keywords, as then it will use regex).